# How to auto change scale in PHPexcel

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpexcel

can anyone help me how to auto scale my phpexcel report in php according to the width of my report? And also i want my report to be auto landscape.

I want my report in phpexcel to autofit in a page according to the width of my report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading section 4.6.10 (`Page Setup: Scaling options`) of the developer documentation:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(1);
```